# Docker [Errno 13] Permission denied with custom user

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to create a docker image and here is my current `Dockerfile`.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM path-to-internal-images/python:3.8
RUN adduser --system myuser
WORKDIR /home/myuser
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -i https://myendpoint/api/pypi/pypi-abc/simple -r requirements.txt
COPY myfile.py .
USER myuser
```

**Build and Run the container:**

```
$ IMG_TAG="docker.abc.com/my-image:0.1"
$ docker build -t ${IMG_TAG} .
$ docker push ${IMG_TAG}
$docker run --rm -it ${IMG_TAG} /bin/bash

myuser@ mymachine:~$ pwd
  /home/myuser
myuser@mymachine:~$ python myfile.py --output-path <PATH_TO_A_DIRECTORY>
```

In `myfile.py` I accept `--output-path` as an argument which is path to a directory (e.g. **/output**) and this could be any value and then it creates a directory using this path provided. However, since I am using `myuser` and not `root` I get following error:

```
  File "myfile.py", line 20, in write_function
    os.makedirs(dir, exist_ok=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 223, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/output'
```

**My question is:** Is it possible to use `myuser` and still be able to create directory structure based on the argument passed when `myfile.py` is called when the container is running? I don't think I can use `RUN chown` here as I do not know the directory upfront, is there any other way to achieve this?

I am relatively new to *containerization* and *docker*, so any pointers would help.

Comment: This sounds like Docker's isolation features are getting in your way.  As you've described this, the output file will be written only in the container's temporary filesystem.  If the major goal of your process is to write a file on the host, would it be easier to run this without Docker in a Python virtual environment?

Comment: Thanks David, Can you pls elaborate on "run this without Docker in a Python virtual environment"?

Comment: Skip all the Docker-related parts; if you just run the `./myfile.py` script on your host system, does it work?  There's a broader [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/) that discusses a couple of the host-based tools for dependency management.  A well-packaged Python application translates fairly straightforwardly into a Docker image.

Comment: Thanks David, I will go through this user guide.